The Difference between state and collective in Giovanni Gentile's Philosophy
Does Gentile conceive of the state as something separate from the collective, that is only united with the individual/the collective, in fascism? In the Philosophical Basis of Fascism he really emphasizes that the state for him is an active spiritual creation of the collective, but in passages like these, it almost sounds like there is a synthesis between collective and the state, in favor of the state (the collective will becomes the will of the state, not the other way around), which presupposes a separateness between the two at least at the stage before fascism.
"That explains the necessity of the Fascist Party and of all the institutions of propaganda and education that foster the political and moral ideals of Fascism, so that the thought and the will of the solitary person, the Duce, becomes the thought and the will of the masses."

Gentile is opposing the point of view of Liberalism according to which State and individual are in some sense opposite; for Gentile «Lo Stato non è tra gli individui, ma nell’individuo» [The State is not between the individuals, but is inside the individual].

Having said that, I'm not a specialist and thus I'm unsure about the term "collective"... but yes, The State is not a bureaucratic system used to control the life of people and individual freedom. See Gentile and Fascist State.

But the role of "collective" is clear if we consider the "corporativism" and its role in Fascist doctrine of State: "according to Gentile, it is not only an economic doctrin, but an ethical approach to a social conception of freedom, where the individual interest is "transcended" for the benefit of the nation."
